# trying to disable wordpress from redirecting to https

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I wish to set up a test version of a wordpress site, without
https, so I can fix various issues that have arisen since it was
moved to a new hosting service.

The test site is redirecting to https - it returns a 301 pointing to the live domain!

I am using nginx, so .htaccess files are ignored (a source of other issues).

The site DOES serve non-php content properly and a .php file with phpinfo()
in it, was served correctly. So it would appear to be wordpress or a plugin issue.

So I renamed the plugin directory to disable ALL plugins and rebooted, and the redirection still happens! I have cleared nginx's cache and the browser's cache.

How can I diagnose the issue further? Below I have copied my nginx config for the test site.

## Statements for testdomain.com on thebe.

server {
    server_name testdomain.com; 
    listen 80;

```
fastcgi_read_timeout  300;

root /home/ian/websites/testdomain/htsecure;
index index.php;
fastcgi_index index.php;
#
access_log /var/log/nginx/testdomain.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# disallow hot linking to images 
location ~ .(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked testdomain.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
# server static files that exist
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
# send .php files to fastcgi 
location ~ \.php$ {
   # Zero-day exploit defense - http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
   try_files $uri  =404;   # only if they exist! 
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root@fastcgi_script_name;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update urls settings in database. For example you can use this link - https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/. I Hope it help you.

Answer (score 2):

Configure Wordpress with your non-https domain by adding the following lines to the `wp-config.php` file (found in your root directory):

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

**Background**

The redirection could be caused by a few things:

1. Your browser has cached the redirect *(try loading the site from another browser)*.
2. Your DNS is improperly configured *(very unlikely the problem here)*.
3. Your web server (nginx) is performing the redirect, either via its global config, a virtual host config, or (if using apache) a directory-level config *(if you can load other PHP files w/o redirecting then likely not an nginx problem)*.
4. Your PHP code is performing the redirect... which could be anywhere in Wordpress...

Ideally, your Wordpress is not performing redirects willy-nilly via some obscure code -- so, disabling all plugins *should* stop the redirection. However, one redirection you may have missed is the redirection that Wordpress itself performs immediately to force the site to load from just the [one specified "site URL"](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).